# How to prevent keychain data to be included in backup and restore process of the devices when using KeychainSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, backup, restore, keychain

I use [KeychainSwift](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift) to save my data on keychain, my problem is, when the I backup and restore my app, from `Device A` to `Device B`, those data from Keychain was included on the transfer.

The question is, how can I prevent it from happening and make my keychain stay only on `Device A`?

This is my code on Saving data into the keychain

```
import KeychainSwift

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    let keychain = KeychainSwift(keyPrefix: "some_key")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        keychain.set("some_data", forKey: "thisDeviceOnly")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use *withAccess* parameter for set method

Possible values you can look on officialKeychainSwift github here
https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift/blob/master/Sources/KeychainSwiftAccessOptions.swift

You need some access value with *ThisDeviceOnly* ending to it not be synced over devices.